# Apple Push Notification using .net http2

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-web-api, apple-push-notifications, http2

I am trying to send apple push notifications using c# dot net code. in that i am able to send notification using

> **gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com**

but i need to use the following host for sending notification

> **api.development.push.apple.com**

api's.

can anyone please send the code or link for certificate based or token based send notification

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

With .NET Core you can use this lightweight [library](https://github.com/andrei-m-code/CorePush) for APN HTTP/2 Push notifications (And also FCM if needed):

```
Install-Package CorePush
```

This is JWT token based sending:

```
using (var apn = new ApnSender(
    p8privateKey, 
    p8privateKeyId, 
    teamId, appBundleIdentifier, server)) 
{
    await apn.SendAsync(deviceToken, notification);
}
```